# How to remove default value in model and add alembic version?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, pyramid, alembic

I am having a pyramid application which uses sqlalchemy and alembic for databases and migrations. I need to remove default specifier from my model class and add a alembic version script to it.

Previously it was like this:

```
class TableOne(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_one"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    field_one = Column(Boolean(name='field_one_bool'), default=False)
```

I removed the 'default=False' from the field_one variable and tried running:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "remove default value for field_one"
```

The alembic version script was generated but all I got inside upgrade() and downgrade() methods were:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Basically, I need to know what should I do in alembic script if i drop a 'default=False' from the model class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`default`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default) of [`Column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) is handled entirely in Python, in contrast with [`server_default`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default). Since removing it has no effect on the database, the generated migration script is empty. In other words you do not need a migration in this case.

Answer (score 8):

If you, like me, wanted to remove `server_default` and ended up on this page, the function is [`alter_column(table_name, column_name, server_default=None)`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column).